# Python Pandas : How to use transform with the DataFrame index?

Tags: python, pandas, transform

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',7], ['A',5], ['B',6]], columns = ['group', 'value'])
```

If I want to keep one row by `group`, the one having the minimum `value`, I use :

```
df[df['value'] == df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('min')]
```

However if I want to keep the row with the lowest index, the following does not work :

```
df[df.index == df.groupby('group').index.transform('min')]
```

I know I just could use reset_index() and deal with the index as a column, but can I avoid this :

```
df[df.reset_index()['index'] == df.reset_index().groupby('group')['index'].transform('min')]
```

Comment: what is your goal, can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by index (if it's not already sorted) and then take the first row in each group:

```
df.sort_index().groupby('group').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 7], ['A', 5], ['B', 6]], columns=['group', 'value'])

idxs = df.reset_index().groupby('group').index.idxmin()
result = df.loc[idxs]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  group  value
0     A      7
2     B      6
```